# How to manage an unmanaged Virtual Private Server

Tags: vps, lamp, centos6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting up and configuring a new VPS server](https://serverfault.com/questions/280413/setting-up-and-configuring-a-new-vps-server)

I just bought a VPS from constant.com. It is unmanaged.

I'm wondering if anyone has a good 101 guide or any tutorial to help me with that.

I'm a fast learner, I just need some good references.

**VPS specs**

OS: CentOS 6.2 64 bits with cPanel

RAM: 512M

Disk: 500GB

CPU: 1xvCPU @ 2.0Ghz

1 IP address

I heard I need to set up a firewall, add a strong password to the root account, create a normal account for me and secure the SSH access.  I think php/MySQL is built-in to the cPanel and I don't need to install it by myself.

Any links/references would be appreciated.

In addition, do I need to configure anything else before I can upload my websites and use the server? Or do you have any suggestions of what I should configure?

Comment: You will need to know general Linux administration (or hire someone who knows this).  ServerFault isn't the place for that.

Comment: Warren: Thanks, jsut readed the post, useful tips!

Comment: Max Vernon: I didn't know this site, thank you, lots of documentations! (EDIT: thanks for editing my post :))

Answer (score 1):

101:

1: Get administrator.

Done.

There is no simple 101 - that is like "I just bought a car, has someone a fast 10 item course to learn how to drive it?".

Sorry.

Unmanaged systems are for those who know what they do, managed for those that do not or have other reasons to not like it;)

Sorry, that IS the bet advice I can seriously give you. Whatever documentation and howto you use, you WILL overlook critical items.